Well-posedness for system of linear PDES
I am studying systems of partial differential equations (PDEs) with smooth coefficients and am trying to understand the general solution. Consider the following system:
\begin{align}
u_x &= a_{11}(x,y)u + a_{12}(x,y)v, \\
u_y &= a_{21}(x,y)u + a_{22}(x,y)v, \\
v_x &= a_{31}(x,y)u + a_{32}(x,y)v, \\
v_y &= a_{41}(x,y)u + a_{42}(x,y)v.
\end{align}
Q: What types of initial and boundary conditions ensure that this system is well-posed? Are there any standard criteria or a general formula like in the case of linear ODEs?
One complication I encounter is ensuring the compatibility condition $u_{xy}=u_{yx}$
​To address this issue, let's consider a simpler system that might bypass this complication given by:

System A:
\begin{align}
 u_x &= b_{11}(x,y)u + b_{12}(x,y)v, \\
 v_x &= b_{21}(x,y)u + b_{22}(x,y)v.
 \end{align}
System B:
\begin{align}
 u_x &= c_{11}(x,y)u + c_{12}(x,y)v, \\
 v_y &= c_{21}(x,y)u + c_{22}(x,y)v.
 \end{align}

For these simpler systems, what are the  criteria for existence of the solution? How does a general solution to these systems look like?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Normally, the study of well-posedness involves establishing an isometry between the properly chosen function spaces. Why this is important is because an equation may be well-posed under one framework (Hilbertian) but ill-posed in other sense (Schauder or classical sense for example). A typical result would be to establish such an estimate:
$$|\text{soln}|V \leq c |\text{rhs}|{H_1} + |\text{bc}|_{H_2}, $$
where $V, H_1, H_2$ are properly chosen function spaces.

It is necessary to specify a topology on the function space to which $u$ and $v$ belong, for otherwise we cannot speak of well posedness.

System A
\begin{align}
u_x &= b_{11}(x,y)u + b_{12}(x,y)v, \\
v_x &= b_{21}(x,y)u + b_{22}(x,y)v.
\end{align}
This system involves derivatives with respect to (x) only. It can be treated as a system of ordinary differential equations (ODEs) in $x$ with $y$ as a parameter.
Initial Conditions:
To ensure the well-posedness of this system, we require initial conditions at $x = x_0$:
$$
u(x_0, y) = f(y), \quad v(x_0, y) = g(y).
$$
The Solution:
The system can be written in matrix form as:
$$\frac{d}{dt} X = A X,$$
where
$$X=\begin{pmatrix}
u \\
v
\end{pmatrix} \text{  and  } A= \begin{pmatrix}
b_{11}(x,y) & b_{12}(x,y) \\
b_{21}(x,y) & b_{22}(x,y)
\end{pmatrix},$$
namely
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\begin{pmatrix}
u \\
v
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
b_{11}(x,y) & b_{12}(x,y) \\
b_{21}(x,y) & b_{22}(x,y)
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
u \\
v
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
As a general explination, let's assume that the matrix $A= A(x,y)$ is diagonalizable, i.e. $A = P^{-1} B P$, then we have
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} X = AX = P^{-1} D P \Rightarrow X= C e^{P^{-1}D P}= C P^{-1}e^{D}P
\end{align}
where $C$ is a constant which can be determine by the initial values. Therefore, in this case the system is well-posed in a domain when the matrix $A$ is diagonalizable. You can find a characterization for all the cases too, i.e when the matrix $A$ has a generalized eigenvalues, or when the solution behave like a center manifold.
By standard theory for systems of linear ODEs, if the coefficients $b_{ij}(x,y)$, $i,j=1,2$ are continuous in $x$ and $y$, the existence and uniqueness of the solution are guaranteed by the Picard-Lindelöf theorem using a sutable norm space.
System B
\begin{align}
u_x &= c_{11}(x,y)u + c_{12}(x,y)v, \\
v_y &= c_{21}(x,y)u + c_{22}(x,y)v.
\end{align}
As you may can see that this system can written as:
\begin{align}
\nabla \begin{pmatrix} u\\v\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} c_{11}+c_{21}\\c_{12}+c_{22}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} u\\v\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
The well-psedness conditions of this system can be determined by Lax-Milgram theorem.

Lax-Milgram cannot be used, this system is first-order.
